# strategies for avoiding io with dask opportunistic caching (or other)

Tags: dask

I have a question about reducing file io when indexing into a dask array constructed from a folder of 3D tiffs loaded with `dask.delayed` pretty much exactly [as described in the docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#using-dask-delayed), and similar to the `dask-image` approach: My 4D (tzyx) `dask.array<stack, shape=(600, 65, 512, 512), dtype=uint16, chunksize=(1, 65, 512, 512), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>` is constructed with a bunch of `dask.delayed(skimage.io.imread)` calls reading 3D tiff stacks..

With opportunistic caching, I can minimize io events on *full* 3D views (i.e. `stack[0].compute()` called multiple times will only read the tiff file once), but if I sequentially index into that stack at different planes, as would be done when changing z position (e.g. `stack[0,1].compute()` ... `stack[0,2].compute()` ... ), then each "plane" of the z stack incurs a new read.  I'm wondering whether the best solution for this is to perhaps make a different `dask.delayed` image reader function that has its own simple caching mechanism to re-deliver a recently read file (for instance, with `cachey.memoize`), or whether I could generally be using the dask.array API better to avoid multiple reads.

(for what it's worth, my application here is working with the [napari](https://github.com/napari/napari) image viewer).

thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a case of Dask's optimization strategies getting in the way.  I encourage you to try `.compute(optimize_graph=False)` in each case and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: will try and let you know.  thanks for the quick response!

Comment: with `stack[0].compute(optimize_graph=False)`, it ends up reading every file in the dask array...

Comment: Ah indeed, we don't cull things.  Well, I don't have a quick solution for you then.  You might have to dive in a bit deeper and figure out what is going on on your own.

Comment: no problem! I appreciate your time.  I'll update here if i hit on a good solution